# httpd, avc: denied { unix_read unix_write }

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, selinux, system-calls, c++

I am new to selinux concept and here I am stuck on how to make httpd perform {unix_read unix_write}
Below is the audit log message.

```
type=IPC msg=audit(1624375715.312:4225): ouid=0 ogid=0 mode=0666 obj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1624375715.312:4225): proctitle=2F7573722F7362696E2F6874747064002D44464F524547524F554E44
type=AVC msg=audit(1624375724.580:4226): avc:  denied  { unix_read unix_write } for  pid=25626 comm="httpd" key=1392707921  scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=shm permissive=0
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1624375724.580:4226): arch=c000003e syscall=29 success=no exit=-13 a0=53030951 a1=4338 a2=1b6 a3=6b items=0 ppid=25612 pid=25626 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)


[root@localhost build]# audit2allow  -w -a
type=AVC msg=audit(1624375724.580:4226): avc:  denied  { unix_read unix_write } for  pid=25626 comm="httpd" key=1392707921  scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=shm permissive=0
        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

[root@localhost build]# audit2allow   -a


#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t unconfined_t:shm { unix_read unix_write };
[root@localhost build]# allow httpd_t unconfined_t:shm { unix_read unix_write };
bash: allow: command not found
[root@localhost build]#
```

**looks like the workaround is to allow httpd_t to run in unconfined_t for shm, which doesn't look right.
I don't know how the shm need unconfined_t for key=1392707921?**

Comment: Have you tried `audit2allow` to generate selinux "policy code" from those messages?
e.g. `ausearch -m avc,user_avc,selinux_err -ts recent | audit2allow -R`

What have you tried so farr?

Comment: @Arikael how to set the type enforcement policy 

allow httpd_t unconfined_t:shm { unix_read unix_write };

Comment: What do you have so far (file context, policy files etc)?

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache ?

Comment: I did audi2allow and it's working but looks like that is not the right way to deal with this problem.
the allow statement is making  httpd_t  to run in unconfined_t for shm, which doesn't look right.
I don;t know how the shm need unconfined_t for key=1392707921?